# Vector2 multiplication causing Segmentation Fault in python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame with python to dable in game development and I just hit a brick wall.  When one of my entities attempts to move using Vector2 multiplication I get "Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault".

The immediate code around the error is this:

```
# destination and location are Vector2, and the difference is a Vector2
vec_to_destination = self.destination - self.location  

distance_to_destination = vec_to_destination.length()

# normalize() returns a Vector2
heading = vec_to_destination.normalize()

# time_passed is a float and speed is an int
travel_distance = min(distance_to_destination, time_passed * self.speed)

# location is a Vector2 as well.
self.location += travel_distance * heading
# The previous line is where the Segmentation fault occurs.
# The equation looks like this with values filled in:
#     Vector2(747, 183) += 6.435 * Vector2(-0.882763, 0.469818)
```

The following may be helpful as well.  You can reproduce the issue I'm having by typing the following into a python intepreter (Python 2.7 and pygame 1.9.2pre):

```
import pygame
from pygame.math import *
v = Vector2(747, 183)
v2 = 6.435 * Vector2(-0.882763, 0.469818)
v += v2
v
```

The full code to reproduce the issue can be found here:
ftp.mattwjones.net
username: share1
password: !share1

Comment: Specifically, in the 3rd method of the 1st class of `game_base.py`, in the `Zombies!!!` folder.

Comment: ha!!! sure enough, that did it.  I replaced "self.location += travel_distance * heading" with "self.location = self.location + travel_distance * heading" and my game runs fine now.  Eryksun, add a reply with that info and I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: This should be filed as a bug against pygame IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only crashes for me with in-place addition. v = v + v2 works fine. (Python 3.2, pygame 1.9.2pre).

I don't see anything obviously wrong in [math.c](http://svn.seul.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/trunk/src/math.c?view=markup&root=PyGame), `vector_generic_math`, but based on my experiments it seems there's a pointer bug somewhere. You should submit a bug report.